# Using articles in front of the word "dawn"

Tags: articles

I came across the following phrase in www.oxforddictionaries.com : "he set off at dawn". At the same time in this dictionary it is not stated that "dawn" is a mass noun. I would like to ask therefore, why there is no article in front of dawn in the phrase?

Comment: Because some nouns don't have attached articles. They are fixed as they're written. For instance: *at noon, at night*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dawn** in your examples being used to tell the time

> at dawn
>   at noon
>   at midnight
>   at two o'clock

none take articles.

Comment: Also last/this/next week/month/year, which don't even need 'at'!